# React-Native and Mapsforge

Tags: react-native, open-source, mapsforge

Trying to create native module for my react-native android application. Codes below is my native java to render / display map using mapsforge library.

I need help please, I need to have a function that returns the instance of the application and if possible it is inside the class that extends LinearLayout. I need to call the function as parameter for the `AndroidGraphicFactory.createInstance(InstanceOfTheApplication)`. You think what I am doing is possible?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import org.mapsforge.core.model.LatLong;
import org.mapsforge.map.android.graphics.AndroidGraphicFactory;
import org.mapsforge.map.android.layers.MyLocationOverlay;
import org.mapsforge.map.android.util.AndroidUtil;
import org.mapsforge.map.android.view.MapView;
import org.mapsforge.map.datastore.MapDataStore;
import org.mapsforge.map.layer.cache.TileCache;
import org.mapsforge.map.layer.renderer.TileRendererLayer;
import org.mapsforge.map.model.MapViewPosition;
import org.mapsforge.map.reader.MapFile;
import org.mapsforge.map.rendertheme.InternalRenderTheme;

import java.io.File;

public class CustomMapView extends LinearLayout {

    private Context context;
    private MapView mapView;
    private TileCache tileCache;
    private TileRendererLayer tileRendererLayer;
    private MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;
    private MapViewPosition mapViewPosition;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private static final String map = "philippines.map";

    public CustomMapView(Context context) {

        super(context);

        // set context
        this.context = context;

        // need help here ...
        AndroidGraphicFactory.createInstance(this.getApplication());

        // inflate map.xml | setContentView
        inflate(this.context, R.layout.map, this);

        // create map layout
        create();

        // start map
        start();

    }

    /**
     * Create map layout
     * and controls.
     */
    private void create() {

        this.mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        this.mapView.setClickable(true);
        this.mapView.getMapScaleBar().setVisible(true);
        this.mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        this.mapView.getMapZoomControls().setZoomLevelMin((byte) 10);
        this.mapView.getMapZoomControls().setZoomLevelMax((byte) 20);

        // create a tile cache of suitable size
        this.tileCache = AndroidUtil.createTileCache(
            context, 
            "mapcache", 
            mapView.getModel().displayModel.getTileSize(), 
            1f, 
            this.mapView.getModel().frameBufferModel.getOverdrawFactor()
        );

    }

    /**
     * Start map
     */
    private void start() {

        this.mapView.getModel().mapViewPosition.setCenter(new LatLong(14.788405, 121.069563));
        this.mapView.getModel().mapViewPosition.setZoomLevel((byte) 12);

        // tile renderer layer using internal render theme
        MapDataStore mapDataStore = new MapFile(getMapFile());

        this.tileRendererLayer = new TileRendererLayer(
                tileCache,
                mapDataStore,
                this.mapView.getModel().mapViewPosition,
                false,
                true,
                true,
                AndroidGraphicFactory.INSTANCE
        );

        tileRendererLayer.setXmlRenderTheme(InternalRenderTheme.OSMARENDER);

        // only once a layer is associated with a mapView the rendering starts
        this.mapView.getLayerManager().getLayers().add(tileRendererLayer);

    }

    /**
     * Get map file
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private File getMapFile() {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        // absolute path of internal Downloads folder
        String dirDownloads = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
        File file = new File(dirDownloads + "/" + map);

        return file;

    }

}
```

Comment: it doesn't support the react-native, only android and desktop app. if you still need to use this library, then should make the native module and integrate into your project.

Comment: Thank you @nika95, I am doing it right now, but i got stuck in `AndroidGraphicFactory.createInstance(this.getApplication());` could you please advice me if what to do on this problem? Please revisit my question I will put the code. Thanks

Comment: What is the `react-native` tag for?

Comment: Trying to create native module for my react-native android application. The above sited code is my native java to render / display map using mapsforge library. Thank you

Comment: The issue is related to `mapsforge` library. If you mention what `stuck` means we can help better. I believe you are getting an error at that line, because there is no method called `getApplication` associated with a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, my phrases in the question is not very clear. Is it possible to get an instance of application inside the the class that extends LinearLayout? Or can i pass application instance from react-native Javascript going to Native (Java Class)? Thanks @10101010 for the guidance in my queries.

Comment: Have you tried creating an instance of `MainApplication`?

Comment: What i did is create another activity that handles the mapview, maybe my solution is not the proper way of doing it but since it is working I think it is good to go now. Thanks @10101010