# new Thread and React Native. Add Mapsforge library

Tags: java, multithreading, react-native, mapsforge, react-native-modules

Try to add library **mapsforge** as module to React Native for generating bmp tiles.
But have problem with render of map.
Render tiles runing from new Thread
If i understand correct, this shouldn't work since RN blocked all threads for self work?

Library is very useful, but modules not exist by mapforge in free access =)

Do variants exist for realisations of  render in other thread?

Ty for anwser

`org/mapsforge/map/layer/renderer/TileRendererLayer.java`
**`file TileRendererLayer.java`**

[first step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GeLd.png)

[second step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PosWt.png)

```
public void setXmlRenderTheme(XmlRenderTheme xmlRenderTheme) {
        this.xmlRenderTheme = xmlRenderTheme;
        compileRenderTheme();
    }

    protected void compileRenderTheme() {
        this.renderThemeFuture = new RenderThemeFuture(this.graphicFactory, this.xmlRenderTheme, this.displayModel);
        new Thread(this.renderThemeFuture).start();
    }
```

For test i created additional activity and try run render. But doesnt work too
Reading doc by ReactNative about thread and to clarify about info. Next step is to check status of thread after running application and search info about running map in other Activity with render in another thread or as service. Mb idea is bad.

Comment: hi, perhaps create a separate task https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54461984/react-native-and-mapsforge

Comment: It is better to add code snippets in text instead of images.

Comment: genius @ZabojCampula =)

Comment: @jspcal checked. First result in google, but not helped me